# Referencing keys in a Python dictionary for CSV reader

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, key

new to python and trying to build a simple CSV reader to create new trades off an existing instrument. Ideally, I'd like to build a dictionary to simplify the parameters required to set up a new trade (instead of using row[1], [2], [3], etc, I'd like to replace with my headers that read Value Date, Trade Date, Price, Quantity, etc.)

I've created dictionary keys below, but am having trouble linking them to my script to create the new trade. What should I put to substitute the rows? Any advice appreciated! Thanks...

Code below:

```
import acm
import csv

# Opening CSV file
with open('C:\Users\Yina.Huang\Desktop\export\TradeBooking.csv', 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
next(reader, None)

for row in reader:

    # Match column header with column number
    d = {
        row["Trade Time"],
        row["Value Day"],
        row["Acquire Day"],
        row["Instrument"],
        row["Price"],
        row["Quantity"],
        row["Counterparty"],
        row["Acquirer"],
        row["Trader"],
        row["Currency"],
        row["Portfolio"],
        row["Status"]
        }

    NewTrade = acm.FTrade()      
    NewTrade.TradeTime = "8/11/2016 12:00:00 AM"
    NewTrade.ValueDay = "8/13/2016"
    NewTrade.AcquireDay = "8/13/2016"
    NewTrade.Instrument = acm.FInstrument[row["Instrument"]]
    NewTrade.Price = row[4]
    NewTrade.Quantity = row[5]
    NewTrade.Counterparty = acm.FParty[row[6]]
    NewTrade.Acquirer = acm.FParty[row[7]]
    NewTrade.Trader = acm.FUser[row[8]]
    NewTrade.Currency = acm.FCurrency[row[9]]
    NewTrade.Portfolio = acm.FPhysicalPortfolio[row[10]]
    NewTrade.Premium = (int(row[4])*int(row[5]))
    NewTrade.Status = row[11]

    print NewTrade
    NewTrade.Commit()
```

Comment: How can row be referenced by numeric index and by key? Row is a dictionary so I'm not sure how `row[4]` will work since the DictReader will only use string dictionary keys.

Comment: Just so you know, after your edit you are no longer creating a dictionary but a set.

Comment: Thanks -- yes it looks like I did. Can I accomplish the same with a set vs a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `csv` module already provides this functionality with the `csv.DictReader` object.

```
with open('C:\Users\Yina.Huang\Desktop\export\TradeBooking.csv', 'rb') as f:    
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:

        NewTrade = acm.FTrade()      
        NewTrade.TradeTime = row['Trade Time']
        NewTrade.ValueDay = row['Value Day']
        NewTrade.AcquireDay = row['Aquire Day']
        NewTrade.Instrument = acm.Finstrument[row['Instrument']]
        NewTrade.Price = row['Price']
        NewTrade.Quantity = row['Quantity']
        # etc
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

> Create an object which operates like a regular reader but maps the
>   information read into a dict whose keys are given by the optional
>   fieldnames parameter. The fieldnames parameter is a sequence whose
>   elements are associated with the fields of the input data in order.
>   These elements become the keys of the resulting dictionary. If the
>   fieldnames parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of the
>   csvfile will be used as the fieldnames. If the row read has more
>   fields than the fieldnames sequence, the remaining data is added as a
>   sequence keyed by the value of restkey. If the row read has fewer
>   fields than the fieldnames sequence, the remaining keys take the value
>   of the optional restval parameter.

Comment: The OP is already using `DictReader` but it seems like the code is mixing `csv.reader` and `csv.,DictReader` code

Comment: @Euan Before the edit the OP was not using `DictReader`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @Euan -- that is correct, I modified my code to include DictReader. I am trying to update to include the relevant fields and receive the following error message: KeyError: 'Instrument'

Comment: @YinaHuang Post the first couple of rows in your csv, including the header. That should clear things up.

Comment: @YinaHuang The point is, you don't need to create a new dictionary, the reader is already a dictionary. But you do need to know the header in your dictionary. My suspicion is that "Instrument" is really something like "instrument" or "Instrument " (with a space at the end).

Comment: Yes, thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga! I was spelling it incorrectly so the call function was not able to recognise the header column. Thank you very much! All cleared up.